# Debugigng Flex and Java on Adobe Flash Builder and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, debugging, flash-builder

I am new to the flex development world. I have an environment where Flex is the client and Java is on the server. The IDE's I am using for each are Adobe FlashBuilder 4.5 and Eclipse.

The problem is that I am stuck at debugging across the two languages at the same time. I begin debugging in Flex and at the same time I set a couple of breakpoints in Eclipse. However, when time comes for the program to shift to the server side, it doesn't quite enter debug mode in my Eclipse IDE.

Perhaps I am missing out on linking the two, but from what I have read is that this is automatic. Looking forward to your answers :)

Comment: Flash Builder is just an Eclipse plugin.  If you use Flash Builder "Standalone" edition; it just comes bundled with Eclipse.  I'm unclear if you're trying to debug both Java and Flex from the same instance of your IDE or if you have two IDEs opened side by side.  It's tough to debug "Doesn't quite enter debug mode".  I think you may consider elaborating on what that means.

Comment: umm, I have two IDE's opened side by side, that is Eclipse and FlashBuilder. I setup a couple of breakpoints on my server code(EclipseIDE) and my client code(FlashBuilder). Then I run the project in debug mode and it does kick into debug mode for my client side code, but it does not do the same for my server side code, that is... the breakpoints setup on my server code are bypassed, if that makes any sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Use Emacs(vi) and "trace()" is good enough to me.